# what is the difference between sections and germs in a sheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory

As abovementioned, what is the difference between sections and germs in a sheaf?

By definition, it seems that section is same as germ.

Comment: Given an open set $U$, a section is one of the elements of the group assigned to $U$ (assuming the sheaf is a sheaf of abelian groups). A germ is defined by a direct limit. These are different definitions. What leads you to believe they are the same thing?

Comment: Germs are very local objects (like a germ of smooth functions at a point) while a section is more spread out (defined over an open set, like a vector field on a patch of a manifold).

Comment: A section can be 'spread' over arbitrarily large open sets of a space, a germ is an equivalence class which is determined by arbitrarily small open sets around a point. A section can often be used in both local and global contexts, a germ is always considered in local context.

Comment: Sections are "functions on a large open set". Germs are "functions around a point". If this isn't obvious, why don't you tell us what your definitions are?

Comment: according to your statement a section belong to F(U), F is a sheaf, a germ is an element of a direct limit, so it belong to F(U), this is my doubt.

Comment: And what's meaning of the germs of a section of a sheaf?

Comment: @Potato       How to explain the germs of a section of a sheaf?

Comment: I'm not sure people would use the term "germs of a section of a sheaf." If I did use this phrase, then I would say the germ at $x$ of the section $s$ is its image under the natural map from the sections over some open set to the stalk at $x$.

Comment: @Potato Thank you for your answers. I'm looking for Math216:the foundation of algebraic geometry by Ravi Vakil.

Comment: @projectivelp I think all your troubles will go away once you see a few examples. Maybe try consulting a different source.

Comment: @Potato Thank you vary mach! I'll try.

Comment: @Potato I'm not sure I agree with "And a germ at a point p is a direct limit of groups." This is the stalk at $p$, and I think it is standard to call elements of the stalk the germs. See my earlier comment for a reasonable interpretation of that phrase (although I agree with you that I've never heard people use it before).

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I was typing germ when I meant stalk. I've deleted the offending comments.